# How to maintain login session in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to understand how to login a user and maintain his session using Springs. Is there a website which will give me sample code?

Comment: You have to be more specific. By default [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) will create login form, store user id and credentials in HTTP session, and track user by `JSESSIONID`. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

SpringSource has a [pet clinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) reference app. There is a specific chapter that deals with [security and login questions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) using [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).